# regex Conditions

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex as follows.

```
'#^(VK[1-8][0-9A-Z]+)#i'
```

This is fine and will return true if the string begins with VK[1-8][0-9A-Z], for example VK2TEST. But what if, following [0-9A-Z], there is the **possibility** of a / and more characters, some of which I need to return true and some of which I need to return false? For example VK2TEST/P.

If I need to return, let's say, VK2TEST/P and VK2TEST/M as true, but other alphanumeric characters proceeding the / as false, how do I go about this? Is this even possible? For example...

```
VK2TEST = true
VK2TEST/P = true
VK2TEST/P1 = false
VK2TEST/M = true
VK2TEST/MM = false
VK2TEST/QRP = true
```

My research points me to [conditional subpatterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php), but I don't really know if I'm heading in the right direction with this.

Comment: You should read the basics of Regular Expressions. This character class `[1-8+]` will only match one character, either a digit between 1 -8 or a plus sign character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the following results:

```
VK2TEST = true
VK2TEST/P = true
VK2TEST/P1 = false
VK2TEST/M = true
VK2TEST/MM = false
VK2TEST/QRP = true
```

You can use a regexp like the following:

```
'#^(VK[1-8][0-9A-Z]+(\/(M|P|QRP))?)$#i'
```

This syntax is covered in the [PHP PCRE Meta-Character Syntax page.](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php)

Here are some tips:

- \: escape character
- []: class definition
- +: one or more quantifier
- ?: zero or one quantifier
- (): sub-pattern
- |: start of alternative branch
- $: end of subject

Some notes:

- If you want one or more of a class, the `+` should be outside the class, e.g. `[1-8]+` to include `11`. If you want [1-8] or a `+`, use `[1-8+]`. Also, in your example `[A-Z+]` will match `T` not the extra `EST` characters. To match the word TEST, you can us `[A-Z]+` with the `+` outside of the class definition.
- Slashes, `/`, need to be escaped, hence `\/`.
- If you want to match different substrings you should use a sub-pattern enclosed in `()` while using the `|` branch pipe to separate patterns.

Comment: `VK2TEST/MM` will be true while you not say `$`

Comment: That's true. It's been added. Thanks!

Comment: @Grokify - Thank you for the fast reply. Unfortunately that will not work because it is EXPECTING the /. As mentioned in my post, the / is only a POSSIBILITY. Code in original post has been edited.

Comment: I've updated the answer to make the slash and suffix optional by adding an optional (zero or one) quantifier for the slash and suffix for `(\/(M|P|QRP))?`. This will now work for `["VK2TEST", "VK2TEST/P", "VK2TEST/M", "VK2TEST/QRP"]`

Comment: I can't get that to work for me. I'll fiddle with it a bit and see what I come up with. Thanks!